# Onclick event for textbox in csharp form application

Tags: c#

I'm creating form application on c# . I have dragged a textbox with some text in it.

```
    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Now what is the event for the `onlick on textBox1` ?

I need to add this on that function `textBox1.Clear();`

P.S I searched everywhere. But all i can find is `jquery and javascripts`... No `c#`.

EDIT

I tried onfocus like below..but its not working

```
private void textBox1_OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             MessageBox.Show("dsd");
        }
```

Comment: Your question is currently unclear. Can you elaborate more what you want to achieve?

Comment: is this windows/web application?

Comment: [A `TextBox` *has* a `Click` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.click(v=vs.110).aspx), what is your actual problem?

Comment: this is widnows application

Comment: I have a text box , when i clicked a mouse in the textbox it should call an function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do something when the control is clicked the handle the `Click` event, not the `TextChanged` event.  Presumably you just double-clicked the control in the designer.  That will only handle the default event.  To handle other events, open the Properties window, click the Events button at the top and then double-click the appropriate event.

That said, is `Click` really appropriate?  What if the user enters the `TextBox` using the Tab key?  If what you actually want to do is act when the control gets focus then you should handle the `Enter` event.

Comment: textBox1_Click function is not running when i click on the textbox

Comment: There is no `onfocus` to trigger and you do NOT handle the `GotFocus` event.  As I stated in my answer, if you want to act when the control gets focus then you handle the `1Enter` event, just as the documentation states.  My answer also clearly states how to handle ANY event, no matter what it is.  Just follow the instructions.

Comment: "textBox1_Click function is not running when i click on the textbox":  You can't just write a method and expect it to handle an event.  I've told you how to handle an event.  Do what I said and it will work.  Don't and it won't.

Answer (score -2):

You can handle OnFocus/GotGocus event in the TextBox, and clear the text in the textbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, no, no!  For a start, there is no `OnFocus` event.  Secondly, as the documentation clearly states, application developers should NOT handle the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events.

Comment: please check my question its edited,.,its not working

Comment: are you using Windows Forms/ WPF Application?

Comment: windows form application sir